# Rolling Sum over 90 Calendar date (look back) from given current date in SQL/ Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rolling-computation

```
**Calender_Date**   **Customer_ID**     **Amount**
01-Jan-21          20211003              59
01-Jan-21          20211005              100
27-Jan-21          20211003              25
25-Feb-21          20211003              188
23-Mar-21          20211005              67
24-Apr-21          20211009              43
25-May-21          20211013              21
26-May-21          20211013              89
11-Jul-21          20211009              65
28-Aug-21          20211003              90
```

**Needed:** Considering Customer_ID - Rolling sum over 90 Calendar look back date (from each given current date).

**OutPut Required or Desired Result**

```
**Calender_Date**   **Customer_ID** **Amount**  **SumofLookbackRolling90DayAmount**
1-Jan-21           20211003            59           59
1-Jan-21           20211005            100          100
27-Jan-21          20211003            25           84
25-Feb-21          20211003            188          272
23-Mar-21          20211005            67           167
24-Apr-21          20211009            43           43
25-May-21          20211013            21           21
26-May-21          20211013            89           110
11-Jul-21          20211009            65           108
28-Aug-21          20211003            90           90
```

Comment: Are your sums correct? `2021-03-23` has a rolling sum that is less than its amount and does not include the value from `2021-01-01` (which has the same customer id).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an analytic function with a range window:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(amount) OVER (
         PARTITION BY customer_id
         ORDER BY calendar_date
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '90' DAY PRECEDING
                   AND INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING
       ) AS rolling_sum
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Calendar_Date, Customer_ID, Amount) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 20211003,  59 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 20211005, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-27', 20211003,  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-25', 20211003, 188 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-03-23', 20211005,  67 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-04-24', 20211009,  43 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-05-25', 20211013,  21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-05-26', 20211013,  89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-11', 20211009,  65 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-28', 20211003,  90 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CALENDAR_DATE | CUSTOMER_ID | AMOUNT | ROLLING_SUM |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 20211003 | 59 | 59 |
> | 27-JAN-21 | 20211003 | 25 | 84 |
> | 25-FEB-21 | 20211003 | 188 | 272 |
> | 28-AUG-21 | 20211003 | 90 | 90 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 20211005 | 100 | 100 |
> | 23-MAR-21 | 20211005 | 67 | 167 |
> | 24-APR-21 | 20211009 | 43 | 43 |
> | 11-JUL-21 | 20211009 | 65 | 108 |
> | 25-MAY-21 | 20211013 | 21 | 21 |
> | 26-MAY-21 | 20211013 | 89 | 110 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba121d4451d3c64e95ff1e6b01294ba9)*